# iOS - Presenting View Controller modally from childViewController - no touch events

Tags: ios, presentviewcontroller

I have an issue with my app when I try to present a View controller modally from a child View Controller.

In my app, I have a container view controller named LandscapeViewController. It behaves like navigation controller which allows the user to navigate back and forward and in process swaps in and out the view controllers as childViewController. I set it as rootViewController in appDidFinishLaunching.

Now from one of the child view controllers I need to show a view controller modally, and I do it as follows.

```
MyOtherVC* otherVC = [[MyOtherVC alloc] init];
otherVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
otherVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 300);
[self presentViewController:otherVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I do see the 'otherVC' presented modally but I cannot interact with the button and text field on its view. Seems like I have messed up the view controller presentation chain when trying to present the view controller modally and hence events are not being delivered to the right view controller.  How can I debug/fix this?

Comment: Maybe you're presenting on the wrong viewController. Instead of calling `presentViewController` on `self`, maybe you need to call it on the `rootViewController`?

Comment: @Hodson thanks for the suggestion but calling it on rootViewController doesn't work either. Looks like something is really messed up with view controller hierarchy in my App. Painfully debugging it :)

Comment: Have you gone into Debug View Hierarchy? Anything look out of place?